# Python Maximum Thread Count

Tags: python, multithreading, limit

I'm developing an event / message based application. Each message is sent in it's own python thread to each receiver. Some pseudo code for illustration:

```py
from threading import Thread

while True:
    msg = get_next_msg()
    for receiver in msg.receivers:
        t = Thread(target=send_msg, args=(msg.data,receiver))
        t.start()
```

- Is there a maximum number of threads that can can be run in parallel?
- Is there a maximum number of thread that can be created?

Comment: CPython can run only one thread in parallel, due to the GIL.

Comment: Due to Python GIL you cant achieve parallelism with Python threads and there are no real limits to how many threads you can create.